# Spreedsheet ':number_format' is woking in 'open office' but not in 'Excel'

Tags: ruby, excel, spreadsheet

```
@currency_format = Spreadsheet::Format.new  :number_format => '#,###'
```

I am using this `@currency_format` wherever needed in ruby code. After generating **.xls** file, `@currency_format` is applied if I open file in 'open office', but not working if I open same file in **Excel**.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have complex data (like math of excel formulas), you can use plain .csv and that might solve your problem.

In the case when that is not an option, can you please expand on your question.

Show us some sample data, and outputs, and show us the Format class and an usage of that.